# Is there a way I can return a nested object with two objects in a Proimise.all() method?

Tags: javascript

I want to, first of all, fetch the data of a user, then in that user's history object, I wanna fetch the data of each user there. the problem is, I want to kind of add the amount from the history object together with the user's data fetched as an object or array, but I get an empty object.

```
import users from "@/models/users";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import dbConnect from "@/util/mongodb";

export async function GET(req, { params }) {
  await dbConnect();
  try {
    const data = await users.findOne({ username: params.id }, { pin: 0 });

    const history = await Promise.all(
      data.history.map((user) => {
        const us = users.findOne(
          { _id: user.id },
          { firstname: 1, username: 1, lastname: 1 }
        );

        return us;
        //I get an empty object when i return {user: us, amount: user.amount}
      })
    );
    return NextResponse.json(history, { status: 200 });
  } catch (err) {
    return NextResponse.json(err, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what you're trying to return?

Comment: Why use a separate `findOne()` call for each user, instead of `find()` for all users in the `data` array?

Comment: With this query: `{ _id: { $in: data.map(d => d.id) }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get an empty object when i return `{user: us, amount: user.amount}`

The problem is that `us` is again a promise (which serialises to an empty JSON object), you would need to wait for it:

```
const history = await Promise.all(
  data.history.map(async (user) => {
    const us = await users.findOne(
//             ^^^^^
      { _id: user.id },
      { firstname: 1, username: 1, lastname: 1 }
    );

    return {user: us, amount: user.amount}
  })
);
```